# Display MSWord file content in any browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to display content of word file in browser same like we display pdf file in browser. I don't want any plugin because if I use plugin I have to install for all browser. I want just one solution which works in all browser.

I have searched on google, but I found all link which directly download word file and open it.

Currently I am using object tag for displaying pdf file but it is not working for word file. It is showing message: *The plug-in is not supported.*

Answer (score 1):

Using a browser plug-in (such as the free [Word Viewer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=4)) is by far the easiest method, and arguably the most correct - however, there are some alternatives if you really don't want to do this:

- Convert the Word document to another format (e.g. HTML/PDF) on-the-fly before the response is sent. For Word 97-2003 documents, you can do this with VSTO/Automation. For Word 2007+ documents, you can use the [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=30425) (although you will have to write the conversion algorithm yourself).
- Use an XSL stylesheet to transform the Word markup (docx) into html/css. You can do this server-side or, potentially, with client-side scripting (JavaScript). Some useful resources [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2008/09/29/transforming-open-xml-documents-using-xslt.aspx) and [here](https://github.com/rnathanday/docx2html.xsl).

Comment: Well, I can't force any end-user who is using my application to install any plugin. So I have to find custom way.

Answer (score 0):

Great question. In principle, browsers only *really* tend to support viewing websites (e.g. `html`). Most, however, also support viewing PDFs, and, as you've correctly identified, you *could* use plugins to extend the behaviour. Crucially, though, some browsers provide document viewing with a `javascript`-based viewer.

I wasn't aware of it before you asked, but there are apparently `javascript` implementations of non-PDF document readers--for example, [ViewerJS](http://viewerjs.org/)--that seem to directly support `.odt`. With a little digging, you might be able to find an implementation/plugin for a `javascript` viewer that supports `.docx`. However, I can't recommend one from personal experience at the moment. I *would* recommend searching for `javascript document viewers` though.

Comment: I' m sorry but ViewerJS don't help me to view word file inside browser.

Comment: Directly rendering `.docx`'s can be particularly tricky unless someone’s implemented the various drawing/typography rules for it. As a half-fix, you might be able to find a `.docx` to `.odt` or `.docx` to `.pdf` converter that you can plug into it. Either way, you might end up with weird mis-rendering issues unless you pre-convert it into a `.pdf` server-side with an actual copy of word itself (or open-source equivalent, provided the document isn't overly complicated).

Comment: hmm so at last I have only easy option - Convert to PDF and use it.

Comment: Yeah, it's a little annoying, I know. It is because accurately typesetting and drawing a document is a quite complicated process that we take for granted. Each document-editor vendor have subtly different interpretations of how to do it. If you're client is writing documents in word, and you want to guarantee it looks *exactly* as they wrote it, then *ideally* you should perform the conversion to `.pdf` *via* word automation. If you're OK with some artefacts then go ahead and either convert it client side or use an open-source server-side converter.